# Testing out filters on images and videos gives different results

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I am testing out different filters on images and videos because I want to later add text then concat various clips together.

For the image:
`ffmpeg -i input_img -filter_complex "[0]drawtext=<...drawtext...>[a]" -map [a] out_img`

For the video `ffmpeg -i input_video -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=<...drawtext...>[v1]" -map [v1] out_video`

The image script correctly adds the image filter but the video one doesn't apply anything. Is it because it's only applying the text to the first frame?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of using [0:v] I just used [0] and it worked. If someone could explain why it worked that would be great